# How can I remove just one item from the toolbar in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm making a custom blog post editor page using CKEditor (full), and for various reasons I don't want the save button appearing. I looked [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar), but it seems that I would have to rewrite the entire toolbar item-by-item which would take ages, so is there a way to do this without either taking out the 'document' set of tools (I want the rest of them, just not save) or rewriting each individual item of the toolbar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you linked is how you do it.  It's not a whole lot of code to define what you need in your config file

Comment: OK, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better / faster way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`removePlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removePlugins) or [`removeButtons`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removeButtons) options.

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,font';    
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,JustifyCenter';
```